# The upper limit of core usage in numpy vector operation

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, blas

I love numpy because multi cores are automatically used on vector operation.

But, I recently noticed that only 4 cores are used although my machine has 8 cores.

[image]

Why doesn't numpy use all cores in the machine? Is it possible to let numpy use more cores on numpy's vector operation?

I'm using Mac OSX 10.8.

### Update

`np.show_config()` shows below:

```
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/Users/john/.pyenv/versions/anaconda-2.0.1/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/Users/john/.pyenv/versions/anaconda-2.0.1/include']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/Users/john/.pyenv/versions/anaconda-2.0.1/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/Users/john/.pyenv/versions/anaconda-2.0.1/include']
openblas_lapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/Users/john/.pyenv/versions/anaconda-2.0.1/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/Users/john/.pyenv/versions/anaconda-2.0.1/include']
blas_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/Users/john/.pyenv/versions/anaconda-2.0.1/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/Users/john/.pyenv/versions/anaconda-2.0.1/include']
mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/Users/john/.pyenv/versions/anaconda-2.0.1/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/Users/john/.pyenv/versions/anaconda-2.0.1/include']
```

Comment: *"I love numpy because multi cores are automatically used on vector operation."* - this is only true for certain functions that call BLAS/LAPACK library functions (e.g. matrix multiplication). This isn't a feature of numpy itself, but rather depends on which BLAS/LAPACK libraries numpy is linked against at runtime. What is the output of `numpy.show_config()`?

Comment: @ali_m Thank you. Please see updated comment.

Answer (score 2):

`MKL`, ideally already uses, an optimized number of threads for your system. You can check those like this:

```
python -c "import ctypes; mkl_rt = ctypes.CDLL('mkl_rt.dll'); print mkl_rt.mkl_get_max_threads()"
```

If you need to change it you might want to change MKL_NUM_THREADS environment variable:

```
python -c "import ctypes; mkl_rt = ctypes.CDLL('mkl_rt.dll'); print mkl_rt.mkl_get_max_threads()"
```

For more on MKL multi-threading check [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/recommended-settings-for-calling-intel-mkl-routines-from-multi-threaded-applications), and the [API](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522112).

I'm quoting [Anton Malakhov](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-distribution-for-python/topic/567669), from Intel. You might want to check that question (Configure number of processors available to MKL NumPy) since it's very similar to yours.

Comment: Thank you very much! But, `OSError: dlopen(mkl_rt.dll, 6): image not found` happens. I've tried `mkl_rt.dylib`, `mkl_rt.so`, and `mkl_rt.lib`. Both of them occurs the same error.

Comment: @rkjt50r983 I think it's because it is failing in finding them. The path will depend on your system but you should be able to locate it in your Python installation than here: `Lib\site-packages\numpy\core`

Comment: @rkjt50r983 Just noticed you are on Anaconda. You might want to take a look at this if you are getting Fatal Error with the above recipe (I have the same problem in WinPython). Link: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6923